# Layering: Issues Layering Navbar on side with other elements....?

Tags: html, css, z-index, nav, layer

I'm going to try to explain this the best that I can. This picture represents the layout I'm trying to achieve.

[image: This is a Picture of the Layout I'm going for]
I'm trying to have a navbar on the side. I'm using bootstrap so this is about a col-md-3 for row layout. I'm able to get it into my document, but what I am having a hard time with is *layering* this nav bar on top of the body tag.

I have a body tag that has an image set to the background with no-repeat and background-size 100% and all of that. But it always covers the nav bar. How can I get the navbar (as well as other elements) to layer *on top of* it. I was hoping that I could do this with z-index, but after half an hour of playing around with this, I think maybe I don't understand z-index nearly as much as I thought it did.

Heres my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "navWrap row">
    <div class = "col-md-3">
        <div class = "brand">


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Heres my CSS:

```
body {

    background-image:url(img/carousel-lifestyle.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}

.col-md-3 {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.brand {
    background-image:url(img/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-26%20at%205.38.31%20PM.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 75px;
    height: 200px;
    padding:20px 100px 20px 10px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amwill/c8j7hd0k/) and i'm not able to reproduce the problem (tested in chrome)

Comment: That's weird, because [this](http://i.imgur.com/UWhPVkQ.jpg) is what i'm getting with the exact same code. I even changed the background color to purple so you can see what's actually happening. Could this be a media queries issue? Because it does seem to be working fine at a smaller viewport size.

Comment: @cocoa I was actually able to reproduce same the problem with your jsfiddle when I made the viewport window wider.

Comment: i think your issue is with this media query: `@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
}`

Comment: Actually, it seems that it only breaks when I have position: fixed; set on the body. With no position selector for this it works just fine. But I need a fixed background. Any other thoughts anyone?